# Can we extend a module in the same file

Tags: f#

Inorder to interop with c#, I do the following

```
namespace foo

type a = ...

module myhelper =
    let d = ...

open myhelper

type b = ...

module myhelper = // module name duplication error
    ...
```

I wanna add more functions which could use type b, so I have to write them after type b declaration, but I don't want to create a new module each time, what should I do?

Global module could help, But, I don't want my c# code to access my type using mymodule.a. So I didn't use a global module but a global namespace

Is there any better structure ideas.

Comment: Why don't you declare type `b` before or inside module `myhelper`? If you need to use a few module functions to define type `b`, you can always declare type `b` first and augment it by type extension `type b with` later.

Comment: @pad however, then the extension method of type b cannot access the local variables (let or default parameters) of type b which was defined earlier

Answer (score 1):

Such subtle interdependencies tend to make your library intractable as it grows. F# helps by preventing this, or at least forcing it to be explicit.

Based on your abbreviated example, you could either define an interface (that `myhelper` targets and `b` implements) or use mutually recursive types:

```ml
type MyHelper =
  static member M1() = ()
  static member M2() = let b = B() in b.M4()
and B() =
  member x.M3() = MyHelper.M1()
  member x.M4() = ()
```